# How to run Linux gui apps on macOS (e.g. via XQuartz)

Tags: unix, xquartz

I'm trying to run some Linux applications on macOS. I have installed `XQuartz` but if I attempt for instance to run `firefox` it does *something* - i.e. the `firefox` process can be seen by `ps`:

```
$ps -ef | grep firefox
  502 29337 29230   0 11:59AM ttys032    0:00.01 X /Users/steve/Downloads/firefox/firefox
```

.. But it does *not* show up as an `X` app:

So which additional steps are required to get Linux binaries to run?

Comment: You can‘t run the Linux version of Firefox (or any other application) on macOS. Which specific version did you download/install?

Comment: um .. _huh_  what is `XQuartz` about?   oh that's _one_ thing I should change to `xquartz`: updating OP but still does not launch

Comment: XQuartz implements the APU that X11 lib calls can make to write to and read from the macOS graphics layer. It does not allow other programs linked for another OS to run. You can build firefox to use X11 on macOS

Comment: I see. So then wha's actually going on under the hood when `xedit` is run via `xquartz` - i.e. how is it different than the firefox scenario?

Comment: Software that uses X11 still has to be separately compiled for different platforms. The versions of xedit, xeyes, etc. that come with XQuartz are compiled for macOS, and those binaries will not run on Linux. Similarly, the Linux version of Firefox is not compiled for macOS.

Comment: I want MNEMONICS - so in some cases I DO want to run Linux versions of the same program.  Someone who highly values using the keyboard vs the mouse would likely understand.  And no I am  not going to  manually create over one hundred shortcuts for a single application..

Comment: I made a rather heavy-handed edit to cover your scope update while trying to keep the existing answer relevant.

Comment: @nohillside: hard but nice work :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't launch the Linux version of Firefox on macOS, because it is a binary for Linux calling libraries from Linux and calling system calls of Linux.

You have to build a macOS version of Firefox on macOS from the source tree you download from here:

```
https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
```

through the traditionnal steps:

```
./configure
make
/usr/bin/sudo make install
```

And during the `configure` step, you will have to take care to use the standard sets of X11 libraries (disclaimer: I didn't test this).

Answer (score 1):

macOS can‘t run binaries compiled for Linux for the same reason it can't run Windows binaries: the underlying architecture and the required libraries are different. For Windows binaries there are `wine` and CrossOver, I‘m not aware of something similar for Linux binaries. If you have access to the source code, you can try to port/compile it yourself. Or you can try to install it through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: Virtualization? Too complex?

Comment: @danielAzuelos Probably doable (it works for `wine` after all), but given the availability of VirtualBox & friends the effort may be too high compared to the gains.